# Swift: Saving (Over writing) & Loading CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

First off, let me explain my app and its flow. The app opens, and the user creates a profile (stores all the data through `Core Data`). After the user clicks on create, it sends them to a Console Screen (which displays parts of the information the user input, such as their name through a segue). Theres a tab that lets them EDIT their profile (name, weight, address, etc). When the user edits their info (to change their name, weight, etc), it should also update the info displayed on the Console Page.

I've gotten the data to save and load.  The issue I'm having is when trying to edit the data from the Edit Profile screen...  The user changes the text in a field, and clicks save.  For some reason, the data is NOT saving...at least that's what I believe it to be the issue.  When the "Save" button is pressed, the text fields go back to what the user originally input on the Create Profile screen, regardless of what text is input.

Code following...

Person.swift

```
// This struct would to get the data from the user
struct PInfo {
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
var cityState: String?
var streetAddress: String?
var gender: String?
var weight: NSNumber?
var phoneNumber: String?
var contactName: String?
var contactPhone: String?    
}

func save(withPersonInfo p: PInfo, withContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! Person

    managedObject.firstName = p.firstName
    managedObject.lastName = p.lastName
    managedObject.cityState = p.cityState
    managedObject.streetAddress = p.streetAddress
    managedObject.gender = p.gender
    managedObject.weight = p.weight as! Int16
    managedObject.phoneNumber = p.phoneNumber
    managedObject.contactName = p.contactName
    managedObject.contactPhone = p.contactPhone

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Saved Successful")
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}

func fetchSingleUser(withContext context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> PInfo {

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    let coreData_items = try? context.fetch(request)

    guard let items = coreData_items,
        let firstItem = items.first
        else {
            fatalError("Error while querying")  }
    print("Loaded CoreData Items: \(firstItem)")

    return PInfo(firstName: firstItem.firstName!, lastName:firstItem.lastName!, cityState: firstItem.cityState!, streetAddress: firstItem.streetAddress!, gender: firstItem.gender!, weight: firstItem.weight as NSNumber, phoneNumber: firstItem.phoneNumber!, contactName: firstItem.contactName, contactPhone: firstItem.contactPhone)
}

func userDataExists(withContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    let coreData_items = try? context.fetch(request)

    guard let items = coreData_items,
        let _ = items.first
        else {
            return false  }

    return true
}
```

EditProfileViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Save to CoreData
    saveUsersInfo()

    alertPopup(title: "Saved!", message: "Your information has been updated!")
    updateTextFields() 
}

    func updateTextFields() {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let userInformation = fetchSingleUser(withContext: managedContext)

        //Set UI Text Fields with Users Data
        firstNameField.text = userInformation.firstName!
        lastNameField.text = userInformation.lastName!
        weightInputField.text = String(describing: userInformation.weight!)
        genderInputField.text = userInformation.gender!
        phoneNumberField.text = userInformation.phoneNumber!
        streetAddressField.text = userInformation.streetAddress!
        cityStateInputField.text = userInformation.cityState!
        contactNameField.text = userInformation.contactName
        contactPhoneNumberField.text = userInformation.contactPhone
        print("Updated User Info Text Fields")
    }

       func saveUsersInfo() {
        //Save to CoreData
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let userInfo = PInfo(firstName: firstNameField.text!, lastName: lastNameField.text!, cityState: cityStateInputField.text!, streetAddress: streetAddressField.text!, gender: genderInputField.text!, weight: Int16(weightInputField.text!)! as NSNumber, phoneNumber: phoneNumberField.text!, contactName: contactNameField.text!, contactPhone: contactPhoneNumberField.text!)
        save(withPersonInfo: userInfo, withContext: managedContext)
        print("User Info Saved")

        updateTextFields()

    }
}
```

I BELIEVE it's an issue with saving (due to debugging), but I'm not familiar enough with `CoreData` to know exactly what the issue is.

Any help/info is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need the `PInfo` struct - Core Data is an object persistence system.  Use `Person` (Which Xcode has made for you automatically based on your Enity) rather than `NSManagedObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your data is being saved.  But you are creating a new object each time, rather than updating the values of the existing object.  Whenever you call your `save` method, this line:

```
let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! Person
```

creates a new `Person` object.  And when you call the `fetchSingleUser` method, you fetch ALL the `Person` objects:

```
let coreData_items = try? context.fetch(request)
```

but then use only the first of those items:

```
let firstItem = items.first
```

It happens that the first item is the original `Person` object, with the original values: hence the textFields revert to those original values.

If your app should have only one `Person` object, change the `save` method to fetch the existing object, and update the property values of that instance, for example in your `save` method:

```
var managedObject : Person
let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
let coreData_items = try? context.fetch(request)
if let items = coreData_items {
    if items.count > 0 {
        managedObject = items.first
    } else {
        managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! Person
    }
    managedObject.firstName = p.firstName
    ... etc
} else {
    // coreData_items is nil, so some error handling here
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  It all makes sense now!  I appreciate the help!